# How to press media keys using pynput in windows?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pynput

I need to pres the play media key but i can't find the aproppiate key value

I've tried doing

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
keyboard= Controller()
keyboard.press(Key.MediaPlayPause)
keyboard.release(Key.MediaPlayPause)
```

But it won't work
I don't get any error

Error traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "2.py", line 63, in <module>
    keyboard.press(Key.MediaPlayPause)
  File "C:\Users\nebbu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\enum.py", line 349, in __getattr__
    raise AttributeError(name) from None
AttributeError: MediaPlayPause
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE:

> Since pynput version 1.5.0 media keys are available for use. The available keys are described here: (https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#pynput.keyboard.Key.media_next)

---

Media control still not available on pynput. (https://github.com/moses-palmer/pynput/pull/171)

You can emit a key input event by using a virtual-key code:

```
from pynput.keyboard import Controller, KeyCode


def main():
    keyboard = Controller()

    print('Pausing/Resuming... ')

    keyboard.press(KeyCode.from_vk(0xB3))  # Play/Pause

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

> In the sample we are using Play/Pause virtual key code (0xB3). You can check the full list of possible values here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes